# How to preview installed fonts?

Tags: fonts, mac, font-management

I'm completely new on a Mac. I would like a pointer as to how to visualize a preview of a given headline in as many fonts as possible from those installed on the system. What I need to accomplish is twofold:
1) Discover which fonts are installed on the system.
2) Look how my headlines looks in ALL of the fonts, spending as little time as possible (a screenful of previews rendered using the various fonts would be golden, perhaps with right-arrow/left-arrow allowing me to browse until I find something I like..).

I cannot import my usual Fonts onto this system so I need to use what they have.

Comment: How incredible for @Justin Boo to edit my post and change `visualiSe` to `visualiZe`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FontAgent Pro from [insidersoftware.com](http://insidersoftware.com/) is an excellent font management application which will do all you ask. There are others - Suitcase, FontExplorer, etc. But I simply prefer FontAgent Pro.

You can use the Apple-installed FontBook as well, although it's a tad limited.

**And on the Mac, simply highlighting a font file in the Finder and hitting the Space bar will show a preview of the font.**

Comment: Thanks! Does FontAgent do the preview I refer to? Pressing spacebar only shows me a "given" text, not my headline... not the words I intend to typeset, which was the intent...

Comment: Yes with FontAgent Pro it's got what they call a "Font Player" which will allow you to preview any number of fonts in any given text. So you can type a headline and see how all the fonts look with that headline. Just download the Demo.... you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Scott's suggestions:
http://www.fontexplorerx.com

Comment: Upvoting to say thanks for the answer. I prefer free software though.